# Symphony Fintech (XTS) market-data socket data integration in PyQt6 using python3

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, algorithmic-trading, pyqt6

I'm using python3 to fetch the realtime data from [symphony-fintech (XTS) market-data using web socket](https://github.com/symphonyfintech/xts-pythonclient-api-sdk) but unable to integrate the fetched data into PyQt6 .exe app.

Only getting realtime data using example.py file.

P.S.: I'm new to web sockets.